# Adding Map tags in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, I am trying to add a raw image for an instance prefab object. When I am trying to render the prefab object on **3d** terrain, it is not showing  object. When the same image rendered as **2d** image I used canvas to show the map tags.  Here are my images,

**Expected Output :**

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: "trying to render the prefab object on 3d terrain"... so you are setting the image as a texture within a material that is assigned to the terrain?

Comment: we want map pointers on our terrain, like we rendered in the above image in canvas,what should we do to get the pointer like materials to the above scene

Comment: Instead of raw image, use sprite renderer component

Comment: Yeah , I used it I am instantiating through raycaste on click,I set my sprite renderer prefab to a specific rotation,but during raycasting I am not getting the initially kept rotation.